# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to perform advanced Excel upload using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

Using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API as backend, I am uploading Excel file with EPPLUS package. I have this code.

```
public class LeaveApplication
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public LeaveType? LeaveType { get; set; }   
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } 
}
```

EnumList:

```
public class EnumList
{
    public enum LeaveType : byte
    {
        Annual = 1,
        Casual = 2,
        Compassionate = 3,
        Maternity = 4
    }
}
```

So I have this method for the Excel upload.

```
public async Task<List<LeaveApplication>> Import(IFormFile file)
{
    var list = new List<LeaveApplication>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {

            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
            var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
            var colcount = worksheet.Dimension.Columns;

            for (int row = 2; row < rowcount; row++)
            {
                list.Add(new LeaveApplication {
                    EmployeeId = worksheet.Cells[row,1].Value.ToString().Trim(),
                    StartDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString()),
                    EndDate = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString()),
                    LeaveType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString())
                      ? (EnumList.LeaveType?)null
                      : (EnumList.LeaveType)byte.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString()),
                    Amount = decimal.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString())
                });
            }
        }
    }
    _dbContext.LeaveApplications.AddRange(list);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return list;
}
```

As I upload the records:

1. I want the application to insert only the successful records and display them after upload.
2. The unsuccessful ones should not be inserted, but the fields that failed and the reasons for failure should  also be displayed for correction.

How do I achieve these?

Comment: So far, it looks like you already have the successful path. What about piece of logic handling failures? Did you try adding it? What have you come up with? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: @Prolog - I want to validate the fields. The successful ones will be uploaded while the unsuccessful ones will be displays and the reason for being unsuccessful

Comment: Sounds like a good project, Ayobamilaye. Let us know how you get on.